# Avalonia, save styles to xaml programmaticaly

Tags: xaml

Does avaloniaUI have the ability to save styles to a file, example to xaml programmaticaly?

I created styles by code and i want save it to xaml (example MyStyles.SaveToXAML(path, name) or MyStyles.SaveToFile(path, name, File.XAML))